# Get index of matching elements in array, taking into account repetitions

Tags: python, numpy, matching

I want something akin to a SQL `WHERE` expression with two arrays in Numpy. Let's say I have two arrays something like this:

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([('f1', np.uint8), ('f2', np.uint8), ('f3', np.float_)])
a = np.rec.fromarrays([[3,    4,    4,   7,    9,    9],
                       [1,    5,    5,   4,    2,    2],
                       [2.0, -4.5, -4.5, 1.3, 24.3, 24.3]], dtype=dt)
b = np.rec.fromarrays([[ 1,    4,   7,    9,    9],
                       [ 7,    5,   4,    2,    2],
                       [-3.5, -4.5, 1.3, 24.3, 24.3]], dtype=dt)
```

I want to return indices of the original arrays such that *every possible matching pair is covered*. In addition, I want to take advantage of the fact that both arrays are sorted, so a worst-case `O(mn)` algorithm isn't needed. In this case, since `(4, 5, -4.5)` matches, but occurs twice in the first array, it will occur twice in the resulting indices, and since `(9, 2, 24.3)` occurs twice in both, it will occur a grand total of 4 times. Since `(3, 1, 2.0)` does not occur in the second array, it will be skipped, and so will `(1, 7, -3.5)` in the second array. The function should work on any `dtype`.

In this case, the result would be something like this:

```
a_idx, b_idx = match_arrays(a, b)
a_idx = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
b_idx = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4])
```

Another example with the same output:

```
dt2 = np.dtype([('f1', np.uint8), ('f2', dt)])
a2 = np.rec.fromarrays([[3, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9], a], dtype=dt2)
b2 = np.rec.fromarrays([[1, 4, 7, 9, 9], b], dtype=dt2)
```

I have a pure Python implementation, but it is slow as molasses in my use case. I was hoping for something more vectorized. Here's what I have so far:

```
def match_arrays(a, b):
    len_a = len(a)
    len_b = len(b)

    a_idx = []
    b_idx = []

    i, j = 0, 0

    first_matched_j = 0

    while i < len_a and j < len_b:
        matched = False
        j = first_matched_j

        while j < len_b and a[i] == b[j]:
            a_idx.append(i)
            b_idx.append(j)
            if not matched:
                matched = True
                first_matched_j = j

            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1

        j = first_matched_j

        while i < len_a and j < len_b and a[i] > b[j]:
            j += 1
            first_matched_j = j

        while i < len_a and j < len_b and a[i] < b[j]:
            i += 1

    return np.array(a_idx), np.array(b_idx)
```

**Edit:** As [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831322/774273), I can use `a_idx, b_idx = np.where(np.equal.outer(a, b))`. However, this seems to be exactly the worst-case `O(mn)` solution I'd like to avoid by pre-sorting the arrays. In particular, it'd be great if it was `O(m + n)` in the case that there aren't any repetitions.

**Edit 2:** [Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833496/774273) is not `O(m + n)` if just using Numpy, but it is usually faster. In addition, he has provided a `O(m + n)` answer, so I'm accepting that one. I will post a performance comparison using `timeit` soon, hopefully.

**Edit 3:** Here are the performance results, as promised:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ User           ║ Version           ║ n = 10 ** 2       ║ n = 10 ** 4       ║ n = 10 ** 6      ║ n = 10 ** 8       ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Paul Panzer    ║ USE_HEAPQ = False ║ 115 µs ± 385 ns   ║ 793 µs ± 8.43 µs  ║ 105 ms ± 1.57 ms ║ 18.2 s ± 116 ms   ║
║                ╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║                ║ USE_HEAPQ = True  ║ 189 µs ± 3.6 µs   ║ 6.38 ms ± 28.8 µs ║ 650 ms ± 2.49 ms ║ 1min 11s ± 420 ms ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ SigmaPiEpsilon ║ Generator         ║ 936 µs ± 1.52 µs  ║ 9.17 s ± 57 ms    ║ N/A              ║ N/A               ║
║                ╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║                ║ for loop          ║ 144 µs ± 526 ns   ║ 15.6 ms ± 18.6 µs ║ 1.74 s ± 33.9 ms ║ N/A               ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Divakar        ║ np.where          ║ 39.1 µs ± 281 ns  ║ 302 ms ± 4.49 ms  ║ Out of memory    ║ N/A               ║
║                ╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║                ║ recarrays 1       ║ 69.9 µs ± 491 ns  ║ 1.6 ms ± 24.2 µs  ║ 230 ms ± 3.52 ms ║ 41.5 s ± 543 ms   ║
║                ╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║                ║ recarrays 2       ║ 82.6 µs ± 1.01 µs ║ 1.4 ms ± 4.51 µs  ║ 212 ms ± 2.59 ms ║ 36.7 s ± 900 ms   ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

So looks like [Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833496/774273) wins hands down with `USE_HEAPQ = False`. I expected `USE_HEAPQ = True` to win for large inputs since it's `O(m + n)` but turns out that's not the case. Another comment, the `USE_HEAPQ = False` version used less memory, 5.79 GB at max versus 10.18 GB for `USE_HEAPQ = True` for `n = 10 ** 8`. Keep in mind, this is the process memory, and includes inputs and other stuff for the console. [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar)'s recarrays answer 1 used 8.42 GB of memory and recarrays answer 2 used 10.61 GB.

Comment: Could you add my newly added `Approach #3 : Generic case` from my post into the timings?

Comment: Getting `ValueError: mismatch between the number of fields and the number of arrays` for the edited sample. I am on 1.13.3 NumPy, Python 2.7.

Comment: @Divakar Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an O(n)-ish solution (ish because if repeats are long it obviously can't be O(n)). In practice, depending on input length, one may probably save a bit by sacrificing O(n) and replacing `heapq.merge` with a stable `np.argsort`. As it stands it takes about a second with N=10^6.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

USE_HEAPQ = True

def sqlwhere(a, b):
    asw = np.r_[0, 1 + np.flatnonzero(a[:-1]!=a[1:]), len(a)]
    bsw = np.r_[0, 1 + np.flatnonzero(b[:-1]!=b[1:]), len(b)]
    al, bl = np.diff(asw), np.diff(bsw)
    na, nb = len(al), len(bl)
    abunq = np.r_[a[asw[:-1]], b[bsw[:-1]]]
    if USE_HEAPQ:
        from heapq import merge
        m = np.fromiter(merge(range(na), range(na, na+nb), key=abunq.__getitem__), int, na+nb)
    else:
        m = np.argsort(abunq, kind='mergesort')
    mv = abunq[m]
    midx = np.flatnonzero(mv[:-1]==mv[1:])
    ai, bi = m[midx], m[midx+1] - na
    aic = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(al[ai])]
    a_idx = np.ones((aic[-1],), dtype=int)
    a_idx[aic[:-1]] = asw[ai]
    a_idx[aic[1:-1]] -= asw[ai[:-1]] + al[ai[:-1]] - 1
    a_idx = np.repeat(np.cumsum(a_idx), np.repeat(bl[bi], al[ai]))
    bi = np.repeat(bi, al[ai])
    bic = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(bl[bi])]
    b_idx = np.ones((bic[-1],), dtype=int)
    b_idx[bic[:-1]] = bsw[bi]
    b_idx[bic[1:-1]] -= bsw[bi[:-1]] + bl[bi[:-1]] - 1
    b_idx = np.cumsum(b_idx)
    return a_idx, b_idx

def f_D(a, b):
    return np.where(np.equal.outer(a,b))

def mock_data(n):
    return np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0, 3, (2, n)), axis=1)


a = np.array([3, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([1, 4, 7, 9, 9], dtype=np.uint8)

# check correct
a, b = mock_data(1000)
ai0, bi0 = f_D(a, b)
ai1, bi1 = sqlwhere(a, b)
print(np.all(ai0 == ai1), np.all(bi0 == bi1))

# check fast
a, b = mock_data(1000000)
sqlwhere(a, b)
```

Comment: If you provide an else clause for the `USE_HEAPQ` version which uses `np.argsort` I would be happy to edit my question and accept it as the answer.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Done.

Comment: I have to give you a lot of credit. I wrote up a Cython version of @SigmaPiEpsilon's answer, it still doesn't beat yours.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi If you are Cythonizing anyway you could try and Cythonize `heapq.merge`. Shouldn't be too difficult if you hardcode n=2 and key=abunq.__getitem__.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 : Broadacasting based method**

Use `outer` equality comparison between the two arrays to leverage vectorized `broadcasting` and then get the row, column indices, which would be much needed matching indices corresponding to the two arrays  -

```
a_idx, b_idx = np.where(a[:,None]==b)
a_idx, b_idx = np.where(np.equal.outer(a,b))
```

We can also use `np.nonzero` in place of `np.where`.

**Approach #2 : Specific case solution**

With no repetitions and sorted input arrays, we can use `np.searchsorted`, like so -

```
idx0 = np.searchsorted(a,b)
idx1 = np.searchsorted(b,a)
idx0[idx0==len(a)] = 0
idx1[idx1==len(b)] = 0

a_idx = idx0[a[idx0] == b]
b_idx = idx1[b[idx1] == a]
```

Modifying it a bit, and possibly more efficient one would be -

```
idx0 = np.searchsorted(a,b)
idx0[idx0==len(a)] = 0

a_idx = idx0[a[idx0] == b]
b_idx = np.searchsorted(b,a[a_idx])
```

**Approach #3 : Generic case**

Here's a solution for generic case (with repetitions allowed) -

```
def findwhere(a, b):
    c = np.bincount(b, minlength=a.max()+1)[a]
    a_idx1 = np.repeat(np.flatnonzero(c),c[c!=0])
    
    b_idx1 = np.searchsorted(b,a[a_idx1])
    m1 = np.r_[False,a_idx1[1:] == a_idx1[:-1],False]
    idx11 = np.flatnonzero(m1[1:] != m1[:-1])
    id_arr = m1.astype(int)
    id_arr[idx11[1::2]+1] = idx11[::2]-idx11[1::2]
    b_idx1 += id_arr.cumsum()[:-1]
    return a_idx1, b_idx1
```

---

#### Timings

Using `mock_data` from @Paul Panzer's soln for setting up inputs :

```
In [295]: a, b = mock_data(1000000)

# @Paul Panzer's soln
In [296]: %timeit sqlwhere(a, b) # USE_HEAPQ = False
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop

# Approach #3 from this post
In [297]: %timeit findwhere(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 61.7 ms per loop
```

---

**Utility to convert recarrays (uint8 data) to `1D` arrays**

```
def convert_recarrays_to_1Darrs(a, b):
    a2D = a.view('u1').reshape(-1,2)
    b2D = b.view('u1').reshape(-1,2)
    s = max(a2D[:,0].max(), b2D[:,0].max())+1
    
    a1D = s*a2D[:,1] + a2D[:,0]
    b1D = s*b2D[:,1] + b2D[:,0]
    return a1D, b1D
```

Sample run -

```
In [90]: dt = np.dtype([('f1', np.uint8), ('f2', np.uint8)])
    ...: a = np.rec.fromarrays([[3, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9],
    ...:                        [1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2]], dtype=dt)
    ...: b = np.rec.fromarrays([[1, 4, 7, 9, 9],
    ...:                        [7, 5, 4, 2, 2]], dtype=dt)

In [91]: convert_recarrays_to_1Darrs(a, b)
Out[91]: 
(array([13, 54, 54, 47, 29, 29], dtype=uint8),
 array([71, 54, 47, 29, 29], dtype=uint8))
```

---

**Generic version to cover for `rec-arrays`**

Version #1 :

```
def findwhere_generic_v1(a, b):
    cidx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,b[1:] != b[:-1],True])
    count = np.diff(cidx)
    b_starts = b[cidx[:-1]]
    
    a_starts = np.searchsorted(a,b_starts)
    a_starts[a_starts==len(a)] = 0
    
    valid_mask = (b_starts == a[a_starts])
    count_valid = count[valid_mask]
    
    idx2m0 = np.searchsorted(a,b_starts[valid_mask],'right')    
    idx1m0 = a_starts[valid_mask]
    
    id_arr = np.zeros(len(a)+1, dtype=int)
    id_arr[idx2m0] -= 1
    id_arr[idx1m0] += 1
    
    n = idx2m0 - idx1m0
    r1 = np.flatnonzero(id_arr.cumsum()!=0)
    r2 = np.repeat(count_valid,n)
    a_idx1 = np.repeat(r1, r2)
    
    b_idx1 = np.searchsorted(b,a[a_idx1])
    m1 = np.r_[False,a_idx1[1:] == a_idx1[:-1],False]
    idx11 = np.flatnonzero(m1[1:] != m1[:-1])
    id_arr = m1.astype(int)
    id_arr[idx11[1::2]+1] = idx11[::2]-idx11[1::2]
    b_idx1 += id_arr.cumsum()[:-1]
    return a_idx1, b_idx1
```

Version #2 :

```
def findwhere_generic_v2(a, b):    
    cidx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,b[1:] != b[:-1],True])
    count = np.diff(cidx)
    b_starts = b[cidx[:-1]]
    
    idxx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,a[1:] != a[:-1],True])
    av = a[idxx[:-1]]
    idxxs = np.searchsorted(av,b_starts)
    idxxs[idxxs==len(av)] = 0
    valid_mask0 = av[idxxs] == b_starts
    
    starts = idxx[idxxs]
    stops = idxx[idxxs+1]
    
    idx1m0 = starts[valid_mask0]
    idx2m0 = stops[valid_mask0]  
    
    count_valid = count[valid_mask0]
    
    id_arr = np.zeros(len(a)+1, dtype=int)
    id_arr[idx2m0] -= 1
    id_arr[idx1m0] += 1
    
    n = idx2m0 - idx1m0
    r1 = np.flatnonzero(id_arr.cumsum()!=0)
    r2 = np.repeat(count_valid,n)
    a_idx1 = np.repeat(r1, r2)
    
    b_idx1 = np.searchsorted(b,a[a_idx1])
    m1 = np.r_[False,a_idx1[1:] == a_idx1[:-1],False]
    idx11 = np.flatnonzero(m1[1:] != m1[:-1])
    id_arr = m1.astype(int)
    id_arr[idx11[1::2]+1] = idx11[::2]-idx11[1::2]
    b_idx1 += id_arr.cumsum()[:-1]
    return a_idx1, b_idx1
```

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately that is too memory hungry and much slower if not many indices match. This is due to the fact that it doesn't take into account that the arrays are (or could be) sorted. I was hoping for something along the lines of using `np.searchsorted` and `np.repeat`, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: I did, your edits break my use case, because realistically there **may** be repeats in the data. I guess I could switch between the two, but it still isn't `O(m + n)` or even `O((m + n) log(m + n))`.

Comment: Wow, I just saw your newest edits. Is it possible to make this general? My actual arrays are numpy structured arrays. Perhaps `np.unique` with `return_counts=True` can help.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Could you  post representative sample data in the question?

Comment: I just added example data on your request.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Added tool at the end of the post to do the conversion. So, use the output off it and use the proposed solutions.

Comment: @Devakar Just saw your edits. Once again, the fields may be float, string, anything. It can be a struct of structs. Yours works only for `uint8`. :(

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Well talk about representative sample data huh. Hmm. Post sample data?

Comment: @Divakar Just did. Also, there's another slight problem with your example, if the values in the arrays are high, it still won't be `O(m + n)`, because of the bincount operation.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Nah, I need struct of structs sample as well. Not taking any chance this time :) Also, bincount would be 0(m), m being the length of b. These are done at C level and very fast. The only concern would be the max value of `a` fed to `findwhere`, as that would decided the max size of bincount result. Memory would dictate the terms there, not any O() notation. Why are you so hung up on O() notations here?

Comment: Actually, `np.bincount([1000])` is a `(1001,)` shape array with only the last element equal to 1. `minlength` will only make it longer. So... If I end up with big numbers in there (which I do) it'll blow up, especially when the array has 7 fields and what not.

I'm like 99% sure that anything you can make work without converting to integers, just using equality in some manner, will work.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Post a struct of structs sample as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161332/discussion-between-hameer-abbasi-and-divakar).

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Check out Generic version to cover for rec-arrays added at the end of the post.

Answer (score 1):

### Pure Python Approach

#### Generator comprehension

An alternative pure python implementation with generators and list comprehensions. Could be more memory efficient compared to your code but probably will be slower compared to numpy version. This will be faster for sorted arrays.

```
def pywheregen(a, b):

    l = ((ia,ib) for ia,j in enumerate(a) for ib,k in enumerate(b) if j == k)
    a_idx,b_idx = zip(*l)
    return a_idx,b_idx
```

#### Python for loop considering array sorting

Here is an alternative version that uses simple python for loop and takes into consideration that the arrays are sorted so that it only checks the pairs it needs to.

```
def pywhere(a, b):

    l = []
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    match = 0
    for ia,j in enumerate(a):
        ib = match
        while ib < len(b) and j >= b[ib]:
            if j == b[ib]:
                l.append(((ia,ib)))
                if b[match] < b[ib]:
                    match = ib
            ib += 1

    a_ind,b_ind = zip(*l)

    return a_ind, b_ind
```

#### Timings

I compared the timings using the mock_data() function of @Paul Panzer and compared it with `findwhere()` and `f_D()` the np.outer approach of @Divakar. `findwhere()` still performs best but `pywhere()` does not so bad considering it is pure python. `pywheregen()` fails and surprisingly `f_D()` takes longer time. They both fail for N = 10^6. I could not run sqlwhere due to an unrelated error in the `heapq` module.

```
In [2]: a, b = mock_data(10000)
In [10]: %timeit -n 10 findwhere(a,b)                                     
10 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit -n 10 pywhere(a,b)                                       
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit pywheregen(a,b)                                          
1 loop, best of 3: 12.7 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit -n 10 f_D(a,b)                                           
10 loops, best of 3: 476 ms per loop

In [14]: a, b = mock_data(1000000)
In [15]: %timeit -n 10 findwhere(a,b)                                     
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit -n 10 pywhere(a,b)                                       
10 loops, best of 3: 2.51 s per loop
```

Comment: Hey, your answer isn't ALWAYS linear. To make it so, you'll need to change it. Put `ib = 0` at the top and `if b[match] == j:` before `ib = match`.